# Android webview sometimes not loading images

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a simple Activity to show a `webview` and a back button. Here is the code that I use to load the URL that I want in the `webview`.

The webpage that I am loading in on a server online, it has a few form elements plus a few links that when clicked I need to keep loading them inside the `webview`.

Now the problem is very often the page loads without the images, I can see the form elements though or only blank white page. I am testing this on wifi so internet is working fine.

Why is it not loading images and how can I make sure it does? I even tried making all images in the html page have absolute paths, but that did not help.

Later Edit: I found out what was causing this. Maybe others will run into this. I had this in the manifest file `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`. After removing it the content inside all the webviews is loading smoothly.

Second later edit: It is terrible, I get the initial page load now, but forms are not submitting and after some going back and forward to the webview, new images do not load anymore. Is it a memory problem? How do I make it start fresh every time?

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
wv.loadUrl(filepath);
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the page from a desktop browser?  If the images do not appear when you do that, then this is not an Android web view problemm

Comment: Yes, sure the page is loading great from the desktop and also from my android tablet browser, but not inside the webview, inside the app i am developing.